# How to prevent duplicate append data to a table in jquery/javascript?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

How can I avoid having the same data in my table?

Here's the code:

```
var a = 0;
    $(document).on("change", "#txtInput",function(){
      var inputLength = this.value.length;
      if (inputLength <= 9) { return; }

      $("#contenido").append("<tr><td>" + this.value + "</td></tr>");
      $("p").html('Total Bianuales: ' + (++a));
    });
```

Comment: What you mean duplicate append data ? input value duplicate ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Store the values you've already added, and if the value of the input is already added, don't re-add it.

```
var a = 0;
var alreadyAdded = [];
$(document).on("change", "#txtInput",function(){
  var inputLength = this.value.length;
  if (inputLength <= 9) { return; }
  if ($.inArray(this.value, alreadyAdded) !== -1) { return; }

  $("#contenido").append("<tr><td>" + this.value + "</td></tr>");
  $("p").html('Total Bianuales: ' + (++a));
  alreadyAdded.push(this.value);
});
```

Comment: It doesn't allow me to type in the input entry. I mean I can write the ID but it's not added in the table.

Comment: im not sure what you mean, can you clarify?

Comment: Sure. When I type in the input entry, it doesn't do anything. It's like "it disable itself". But I found out that the problem is with: "alreadyAdded[] = this.value;". When I remove this piece of code, it works normally. I don't how does it affect it. And sorry for my english man, I'm a spanish speaker xD

Comment: wasn't that the point? to not add values that have already been added?

Comment: Yes sir! But the problem is that it doesn't add any value to the table. It doesn't matter if the table is empty or not.

Comment: sorry i had a small syntax error. change that line to `alreadyAdded.push(this.value);` and it should work

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you need to browse the table twice, and check every row. Here a snippet with a example :

```js
//Populate table
for(var i = 0; i<10; i++){
 $('table tbody').append('<tr><td>Row '+i+'</td></tr>');
 $('table tbody').append('<tr><td>Row '+i+'</td></tr>');
 }

//Go along the table twice and check. Remove if the same content.
function cleanTable(){
  for(var i = 0; i<$('table tbody tr').length; i++){
      for(var j = 0; j<$('table tbody tr').length; j++){
      if($('table tbody tr').eq(i).html() == $('table tbody tr').eq(j).html() && i != j){
        $('table tbody tr').eq(j).remove();
      }
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button onClick="cleanTable()">Clean</button>

<table>
  <tbody>
  </tbody>
</table>

<button onClick="cleanTable()">Clean</button>
```

Comment: Can I do it without adding a new button?

Comment: Yeah of course, just call the cleanTable() function after the loading of the page.